# NullPointerException when trying to add a Navigation Drawer (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-menu, android-toolbar

I'm a bit stuck. I have been followng some tutorials and ended up making a `DrawerLayout` like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:entries="@array/menuitems"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left">
</ListView>
</android.support.v4.DrawerLayout>
```

I want this menu to slide in whenever the hamburger icon in my toolbar gets pressed, so I set an onClickListener in my Activity:

```
    hamburgerIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hamburger);
    hamburgerIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                 String[] osArray = { "Bla", "Bla", "alB", "alB", "BLA" };
                 mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);
                 mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                 mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    };
```

I get a NullPointer when I try to initialise the `ListView` (mDrawerList) - and I'm certain that's because the Activity that I'm using uses a different layout to the navigation_drawer.xml, so it is unable to find the ListView in the xml. My question is, how can I use the navigation drawer layout using my main (different) layout?

Any tips are welcome, thanks.

EDIT: 
I used this tag to include the `DrawerLayout` in the main layout

```
    <include layout="@layout/navigation_drawer"
        android:id="@+id/navdraw"/>
```

However, now I'm getting a RuntimeException when opening the main layout "Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v4.DrawerLayout" - then it complains about the setContentView(..) line in the main activity.

I have tried adding the dependency in the gradle script

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
```

But it's underlined in red and says "The support library should not use a lower version (20) than the targetSdkVersion (22)".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
 hamburgerIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.hamburger);
  mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    hamburgerIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
             String[] osArray = { "Bla", "Bla", "alB", "alB", "BLA" };
                 mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);
                           mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    };
```

try again

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the `navigation_drawer.xml` is not the main layout? 
You can use the `include` tag and set the `id`. Then try `findViewById(include_id).findViewById(R.id.list)`.